# Disable button when minlength is not achieved in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to disable save button with minlength as 7 . Save should be enabled only when 8 characters are entered. I have used keydown event for this. This works fine when I start to type the characters, but when I use backspace to remove the characters , save get disabled only when 5 characters are left. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
<input type="tel"  name="mobileInput" autocomplete="off" (keydown)="enablePhoneDown($event,'phoneNumber')" value="{{mobile}}" class="form-control" pattern="^[0-9]*$" id="phoneNo" formControlName="phoneNo" minlength="8" maxlength="8">

 enablePhoneDown($event, type) {

      if($event.target.value.length < 7){
        if(type === 'phoneNumber') {
          this.disableButtonPhone = true;
        }
      }else{
          this.disableButtonPhone = false;
      } 
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `[disabled]`attribute

```
<input type="tel"  name="mobileInput" autocomplete="off"  
 value="{{mobile}}" class="form-control" pattern="^[0-9]*$" id="phoneNo" formControlName="phoneNo" minlength="8" maxlength="8">

<button type="button" [disabled] ="form.get('phoneNo').value <8">Button<button>
```

Comment: just a little hint, i would not bind to a methods result due to exception handling, because he has to assure that any exception won't return anything destryoing the correct state

Answer (score 1):

try to use `[disabled]="disableButton"` in your button element.  This will bind the buttons enabled attribute directly to your boolean variable.